# Rough Volatility and Change of Measure

Tags: volatility, stochastic-volatility

When deriving the rough Bergomi model, Bayer et al in "[Pricing Under Rough Volatility](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2554754)" (2015) perform a change of measure to ensure the price process is a martingale as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: Bayer change of measure]

However, there is recent academic work, such as the "[On the martingale property in the rough Bergomi model](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/electronic-communications-in-probability/volume-24/issue-none/On-the-martingale-property-in-the-rough-Bergomi-model/10.1214/19-ECP239.full)" by Gassiat in 2019, showing that the process is a local martingale and a true martingale under certain conditions as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: current work on martingale properties]

I don't understand how, under the risk neutral measure, the price process is a martingale and yet current work says it's an unanswered question.

Comment: In the Bayer paper, the time domain is $[0,T]$, so any local Martingale is a Martingale. However, in Gassiat, the domain is $[0, \infty)$. Does that resolve your problem?